# Would it matter where in the DOM tree that I insert the external JavaScript resource?

Tags: javascript

I am reading the official Facebook JS SDK script:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

It inserts the created `<script>` tag to the `fjs.parentNode`. Is that by design?

If I write replace:

```
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

with:

```
document.head.appendChild(js);
```

Would it still work?

Comment: Should still work, yes. But unless you have a real reason to, I would advise against changing the code Facebook provides.

Answer (score 0):

Yes both will work but

```
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

This will insert JS before all JS file and other-side

```
document.head.appendChild(js);
```

This will insert after all JS in Head.

Comment: And inserting in one of the locations versus the other will cause what difference in behavior, if any?